# populating TableView with Json Response from web service in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Below is my JSON saved in NSDictionary. I want to load that data in table cell via keys. How can I do that to fill my table view in Objective C

JSON:

```
        {
    age = 55;
    firstName = Demo;
    fullName = "Demo  Female";
    gender = Female;
},
        {
    age = 26;
    firstName = sita;
    fullName = "sita  devi";
    gender = Female;
},
        {
    age = 24;
    firstName = Felicity;
    fullName = "Felicity Smoak";
    gender = Female;
},
        {
    age = 27;
    firstName = sunaina;
    fullName = "sunaina jain";
    gender = Female;
}
```

];

Comment: How are you receiving the JSON info?
Do you need to save it to disk, or can you use it directly from memory?

Comment: If you want to ask a question on SO, it's generally recommended to post the code that you have tried so that we can pinpoint what's going wrong and how to fix it. Can you post any code?

Comment: I don't need to save the JSON anywhere i just need it to show in a custom cell in table view controller.... but i just need to show the data inside "myResponse" Key in the JSON

Comment: define @property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *responseArray as property with strong attribute, self.responseArray = [jsndictionary objectForkey: myResponse]; now use this array to display data in tableview.

Comment: edit your question and post your code. then we can help you

Comment: We mean post your Objective-C code. It will be easier to help you from there.

Comment: Thx @iOS_developer you saved me... :)

Comment: I have 8cells to generate for a table... One more problem is that my table view doesn't populate with data it just shows custom made cell with label tags after loading but when i scroll the table it fill the last four cell data but null values for first 4 cells... Its like my view loads before I get complete response from WEB service.... Guide me in this one please......

Comment: Edited the Title of the Question please refer it again.... thx

Comment: THX buddies I did it.....